# Magento "Product Status Update" event is not triggered

Tags: events, magento, status, product

I'm working on an extension that will receive product information from Magento when saved and do custom processing on the product.

I've spent 2 days until now trying to figure out why Magento is not triggering the event "catalog_product_status_update".

Simply, I change product status by going to Catalog->Manage Products, then select one or more products and use the "Actions" field above the products grid to change product(s) status to "disabled".

When I do that, the product(s) status changes just fine, but the problem is that I don't receive the event for it.
Here's the code I use:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <global>
    <models>
        <mage4ucustomredirect>
             <class>Mage4u_Customredirect</class>
        </mage4ucustomredirect>
    </models>
    <events>
       <catalog_product_save_after>
            <observers>
                <abc>
                    <type>singleton</type>
                    <class>Mage4u_Customredirect_Model_Observer</class>
                    <method>on_catalog_product_save_after</method>
                </abc>
            </observers>
       </catalog_product_save_after>
       <catalog_product_status_update>
            <observers>
                <abc>
                    <type>singleton</type>
                    <class>Mage4u_Customredirect_Model_Observer</class>
                    <method>on_catalog_product_status_update</method>
                </abc>
            </observers>
       </catalog_product_status_update>
    </events>
  </global>
</config>
```

And this is the observer:

```
class Mage4u_Customredirect_Model_Observer
{
    public function on_catalog_product_status_update(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
    {  
        Mage::log( "on_catalog_product_status_update" );
    }

    public function on_catalog_product_save_after(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
    {  
        Mage::log( "on_catalog_product_save_after"  );
    }
}
?>
```

Strange enough, when I try to save a product manually, I receive the event "on_catalog_product_save_after" which tells me that my code is working fine, but it doesn't work for this "on_catalog_product_status_update" event.

Any help is appreciated!

NOTE: I'm using Magento v1.6.2.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your problem is that the update status option at the top of the grid doesn't use any models to achieve the task, it access the database directly. If you look at the `updateAttributes` method in `Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Action` and `Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Mysql4_Product_Action` respectively, you will see that no product or product_status model is loaded.

Unfortunately for you, at a quick glance I don't see any events that you can hook into to capture this. It might require rewriting of the model.

Comment: Thanks Cags ... I thought there's something weird about this event, because my other events have been working perfectly for months now. But if this is true, what is the purpose of this event if it's not being fired?

Comment: The purpose of the event is to allow you to do exactly what you are trying to do. Unfortunately, the person that wrote the update status feature for the datagrid, side steps the model, meaning the status can be changed without triggering the event. There are numerous examples of this sort of thing in Magento.

Answer (score 0):

Your two observers have the same name "abc". This should be unique inside Magento observers list.

Try changing one of them to "abc1", refresh your cache and it should work.

Comment: I could be wrong, but since they are observers for different events I don't believe them having the same node name matter.

Comment: I would take a try anyway, it is a pretty simple change :)

Comment: I've replaced one with "abc1" instead of "abc" ... nothing has changed

Answer (score 0):

This question was asked somewhere in 2012, but in more recent Magento versions, the mass action update for the product grid is processed by the `catalog/product_action` model its `updateAttributes` method:

```
Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Action::updateAttributes()
```

An event is dispatched there:

```
Mage::dispatchEvent('catalog_product_attribute_update_before', array(
    'attributes_data' => &$attrData,
    'product_ids'   => &$productIds,
    'store_id'      => &$storeId
));
```

`attributes_data` is a key-value list with data to be stored for `product_ids` in the `store_id` scope. In your observer for `catalog_product_attribute_update_before` you can check if the status attribute is being updated:

```
$event = $observer->getEvent();

$attributesData = $event->getData('attributes_data');

if (! isset($attributesData['status'])) {
    // we are not updating the status
    return;
}

// do something, for example - if the product will be disabled
if ($attributesData['status'] != Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Status::STATUS_ENABLED) {
   // api call
}
```

Hope this helps for anyone who tries to intercept a mass status update.